# Z-index, blocks superimposed on each other, the references in those blocks above all

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, z-index

```
<style>
a { position:absolute; top:20px; color:#0F0; z-index:5; }
div { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:50px; background:#066; }
.a { z-index:4; }
.b { z-index:3; }
.c { z-index:2; }
.d { z-index:1; }
.a a { left:10px; }
.b a { left:50px; }
.c a { left:100px; }
.d a { left:150px; }
</style>

<div class="a"><a href="#" title="">123</a></div>
<div class="b"><a href="#" title="">123</a></div>
<div class="c"><a href="#" title="">123</a></div>
<div class="d"><a href="#" title="">123</a></div>
```

The desire only one thing that all the links were on the blocks. In ie7 it worked.

To help out.

Comment: <style>
a { position:absolute; top:20px; color:#0F0; }
div { float:left; margin-right:-100%; width:100%; height:50px; background:#066; }
.a a { left:10px; }
.b a { left:50px; }
.c a { left:100px; }
.d a { left:150px; }
</style>
<body style="position:relative;">
<p style="display:block; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; padding:0; margin:0;">
    <div class="a"><a href="#" title="">123</a></div>
    <div class="b"><a href="#" title="">123</a></div>
    <div class="c"><a href="#" title="">123</a></div>
    <div class="d"><a href="#" title="">123</a></div>
</p>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

internet explorer renders many things wrong. Other browsers like safari, firefox and chrome do it correctly.

`position:absolute;`means, that `top`and `left`are measured absolute, that means, according to the borders of the document. You forced all elements to be printed at the same position!

Answer (score 0):

[IE 7 doesn't use Z-index correctly](http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/)

Basically.  No surprises there.

To be more clear:

> When you add css positioning to an element and give it a z-index (other than auto) it creates new stacking context with new stacking levels inside the new context.

See: [Z-index and the CSS Stack](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-stack-z-index/)

So your stacked divs being both positioned and z-indexed have their own stacking context therefore only the top one will show.